# what is the usage of see function(rx) here?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I am working in the string manipulation with the help of REGEX. I am going through some of the cheat-sheets. I noticed an example

`see <- function(rx) str_view_all("abc ABC 123\t.!?\\(){}\n", rx)`

What is the usage of **function (rx)** here ? I am curious to know the answer. Because if i remove **function(rx)** and give a pattern i get the same answer.

`see <- str_view_all("abc ABC 123\t.!?\\(){}\n", "a")`

But here i have to use my variable to see my output. Can you please anyone explain?

Comment: For further understanding, you can read up on lambda functions and the new lambda syntax in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rx` is the name of the function's argument. Coders many times choose the name `x`, probably the most frequent, but the name doesn't matter, just like in a mathematical function you can name it `x`, `y`, `id` or anything you want.
With a function you can pass your variable to it without repeating its code every time you need it.

```
library(stringr)

see <- function(rx) str_view_all("abc ABC 123\t.!?\\(){}\n", rx)
```

Now that the function is defined, just do

```
see("a")
see("AB")
```

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong, function's arguments are always passed between ```{}``` right. But here i don't see the curly braces so can you explain how it works here..

Comment: @Rengaraj You are wrong. Function *arguments* are between parenthesis right after the reserved word `function`. A function *body* must be between `{}` if it spans more than one code line. If not, as it is the case, the curly braces are not needed. (But it wouldn't hurt if they delimit the single code line.)

Comment: Okay now i understood, ```rx``` is the function argument.